# Validate a NSTimer that was invalidated

Tags: ios, objective-c, nstimer

How can I recall or reestablish a timer that was previously invalidated?

I am trying to allow the user to revalidate/restart a timer when they click a button. Is this possible?

Comment: You'll need to re-initialise it.

Comment: you *can* change the fire date, but if it has already invalidated then you need to make a new one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you invalidate a timer, set it to `nil`. Then you'll be able to point it to a new `NSTimer` object.

Example:

```
//When you're done using your timer
[timer invalidate];
timer = nil;

//When you want to use it again
timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(tick) userInfo:nil repeats:TRUE];
```

Comment: Setting a variable to `nil` then assigning a new pointer to it is not the same is reinitializing the previous object.

Answer (score 10):

Unfortunately, no.

[From the docs:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSTimer/invalidate)

> Once invalidated, timer objects cannot be reused.

Just make a new one.